# How can I get kernel / early boot output over my NVIDIA GPU using CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, boot, grub, nvidia

I recently installed CentOS 7.7 with KDE on a machine with both onboard graphics and an NVIDIA GTX 1080 Ti. I got the proprietary NVIDIA drivers installed, but it was quite difficult as I couldn't see what was happening during boot up past a certain point.

I changed the default `/etc/default/grub` to remove `rhgb quiet` from the command line, and I'd get text output up until a message like "dracut pre-udev hook" (though it wasn't always the same step). Then I'd get no further updates, just the same unchanging text, until the X server started.

I tried `plymouth-set-default-theme details; dracut -f` based on a CentOS forum post. It made no detectable difference. I restored `rhgb quiet` thinking maybe `plymouth-set-default-theme` wanted those options, and now I only see the very first line of bootup (`[0.00000] something about TSC`), static, until X starts.

Of course, it "works" now, but I'm hoping I can make it work better. Does anyone know how to get detailed boot output over NVIDIA GPUs with CentOS?

Comment: Exactly what is "a machine"? Be specific. There are millions of different models PCs, laptops, workstations, servers, etc. out there.

Comment: ASUS Z10PE-D8 WS, NVIDIA GTX 1080 Ti, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2683 v4 @ 2.10GHz

Comment: Hm, that should work fine on that hardware. How exactly did you install the NVIDIA drivers?

Comment: Using the NVIDIA `.run` file (`sudo bash cuda_10.1.168_418.67_linux.run --silent --driver --toolkit --samples`). (I'd rather use the `.rpm` but have been told not to...)

Comment: I don't recommend using the upstream binary as you have done. It just makes a mess of the system. You _should_ be using well-designed RPM packages from a trusted source, such as [negativo17](https://negativo17.org/nvidia-driver/) (which I use). Though, because it's such a pain to remove the manual binary package, you are probably going to need to reinstall CentOS.